# how to stop moving text box at specific point?

Tags: javascript, html

i'm developing a web site i want a div to move when a user click on the text box and i need to stop that div below the clicked text box. i have tried

```
var index = event.target.id
```

but it didn't work i 'm using flowing javascript function

```
<script  type="text/javascript">

var cmdStr = window.location.search;

cmdStr = (cmdStr.indexOf("menu_id")>-1)?cmdStr.substring(cmdStr.indexOf("=")+1,cmdStr.length):"";

var isNS6 = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mozilla")>-1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Gecko")>-1)?true:false;
var isIE  = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")>-1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera")==-1)?true:false;
var isOp  = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera")>-1)?true:false;


function init(){
 // if(isIE){
 //   document.getElementById("msg_scroller").style.position="relative";
 // }
}
var incrementVal = 2;
var timer;
var flag;

function scroll(flag){
    var obj = document.getElementById("movingDiv");
    var isIE6 = (document.documentElement.clientHeight)? true : false;`

    var Y = parseInt(obj.style.top);
    var cY = (isIE6)?document.documentElement.clientHeight-173 :((document.all)? document.body.clientHeight-173:window.innerHeight - 173);
    if(flag==1 && Y<cY){
        obj.style.top = (Y+incrementVal)+"pt";
        timer = setTimeout("scroll(1)",incrementVal*20);
    }else if(flag==-1 && Y>0){

        obj.style.top = (Y-incrementVal)+"pt";
        timer = setTimeout("scroll(-1)",incrementVal*20);
    }else{
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
}
</script>
```

and my html is

```
<div id="movingDiv" style="position:absolute;left:100pt;top:150pt;border:1px;width:160px;background-color:lightyellow;font-weight:bold;" >
<textarea style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Potha, Malithi Web , Arial Unicode MS;
                            width: 600px;"  rows="7"></textarea> 
 <text></div>
```

i know to stop this i have to get x,y cordinates but how i get this ?? can some one help me?

Comment: have a google for javascript offset

Comment: Pete- how to connect javascript offset to my function im new to the java script , i have no idea about javascript offset

Comment: I think you'll need to use the following where you need it obj.offsetLeft; obj.offsetTop;